# Android - Read properties file without using context

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a simple class which is not an activity, so I don't have access to context, but I want to read a properties file in my project (rather than on sd card).

```
MyClass {

    public static void readProperties(){
        Properties props=new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/mine.properties");
        try {
            props.load(inputStream); 
        } catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code though, I get a null pointer exception:

> 02-20 15:32:38.396: E/AndroidRuntime(27473): java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
>   02-20 15:32:38.396: E/AndroidRuntime(27473):    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)

Where should I put my properties file in order to be able to read it? I tried `src` , the project root, assets, and also next to MyClass.java, each time getting null pointers. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Eclipse with ADT (not on Android Studio yet).
My structure is something like this:

> -src
>      --main/SomeActivity.java
>      --main/MyClass.java
>      --main/mine.properties
>   -assets
>   -gen
>   -res

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to introduce `Context` via the constructor as a class dependency?

Comment: I have a few classes already and I rather mess with the code in order to keep it cleaner. But would that be the only way?

Comment: Or You can put Context as a part of your method `readProperties` parameter and then call `readProperties` from a class which has access to Context.

Comment: You could also parse the properties file at compile time and expose the properties via `BuildConfig.MY_PROPERTY_1`

Comment: @ataulm, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `gradle.properties` to store some things like API key. Gradle properties are simple key value pairs:

```
tmdbApiKey=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j6f7g8h9i0j
```

The properties file is in the root of my Android project:

```
/Wutson
  gradle.properties
  ... other files/directories
  mobile/
    build.gradle
```

In `/Wutson/mobile/build.gradle` which is the build file for my Android module, I read from my properties file, and use the `buildConfigField` method to generate a static final field in my `BuildConfig` class which is accessible at runtime from classes in my Android module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...

def tmdbApiKey = hasProperty('tmdbApiKey') ? tmdbApiKey : 'provide this in gradle.properties'

android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        buildConfigField "String", "TMDB_API_KEY", "\"$tmdbApiKey\""
    }

    ...
}
```

From a class in my Android module, for example, `MainActivity`, I'm able to access this value:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TEST", "my api key: " + BuildConfig.TMDB_API_KEY);
}
```

will print:

```
TEST | my api key: 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j6f7g8h9i0j
```

unless you forgot to put that property in the file in which case you'd get:

```
TEST | my api key: provide this in gradle.properties
```

A full example can be found at my [project repo on GitHub](https://github.com/ataulm/wutson) (where `gradle.properties.example` is an example of what `gradle.properties` would look like).